# Repository Pattern and Dataset

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm reading through Repository pattern at [The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Under the Solution section, its mentioned

> The repository mediates between the data source layer and the business
>   layers of the application. It queries the data source for the data,
>   maps the data from the data source to a business entity, and persists
>   changes in the business entity to the data source. A repository
>   separates the business logic from the interactions with the underlying
>   data source or Web service.

So, is it apt to call the Dataset an example of Repository Pattern.  Also under objectives section I found

> You want to maximize the amount of code that can be tested with
>   automation and to isolate the data layer to support unit testing.

which, can any one explain with examples ?

Thanks a zillion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: No, they serve different purposes.

*Dataset* [represents *an in-memory cache* of data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and doesn't provide methods to modify data.

In contrast, *Repository* provides methods to operate with data: [objects can be added to and removed from the Repository, as they can from a simple collection of objects, and the mapping code encapsulated by the *Repository will carry out the appropriate operations behind the scenes*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

**ps**: you may find my answer to be not *language-agnostic*, in this case please provide more details along with your question

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. I'm able to understand the concept :)